# Schema folder for IIS resetting its state

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7.5, sharepoint-2010

I am currently working in a Windows Server 2008 R2 enviroment with IIS and sharepoint installed.

I have installed Application Request Routing(ARR) onto the IIS server and it installs some xml files into "%windir%\system32\inetsrv\config\schema"

I have a UAT and DR environment and it seems that in the UAT environment it is working well but once in the DR, every few hours, the files in that folder will reset to its original state before ARR was installed.

Could anyone shed some light as to why such a problem would happen? Or maybe why does IIS reset its state at all?

Comment: Instead adding the solution in the question section (and put solved word in the title), you should put the solution in the answer section below.... See http://serverfault.com/tour

Comment: Thanks for your guidance, i have since posted it as a answer to my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[RESOLVED]
Seems like there was a scheduled task that deleted all .xml files on "%windir%\system32" but not all were deleted as there was different permission on it in "%windir%\system32\inetsrv\config\schema" and the scheduled task was unable to delete it.